# Get value of variable when isset() is used in PHP ternary shorthand operator

Tags: php, syntax, operators, ternary-operator, php-7

In using the shorter ternary operator:

`$foo = isset($_GET['bar']) ?: 'hello';`

If `$_GET['bar']` is set, is it possible for `$foo` to return the value of `$_GET['bar']` instead of `true`?

Edit: I understand the old school ternary works e.g.,

`$foo = isset($_GET['bar']) ? $_GET['bar'] : 'hello';`

but I want to use the newschool ternary which is the even shorter version

Comment: its funny how few of the answer is the same as your example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking about the new (as of PHP 7) [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). You can do something like:

```
$foo = $_GET['bar'] ?? 'hello';
echo $foo;
```

Which if `$_GET['bar']` is null will set `$foo` to `hello`.

> The first operand from left to right that exists and is not NULL. NULL if no values are defined and not NULL. Available as of PHP 7.

Functional demo: https://3v4l.org/0CfbE

```
$foo = $_GET['bar'] ?? 'hello';
echo $foo . "\n";
$_GET['bar'] = 'good bye';
$foo = $_GET['bar'] ?? 'hello';
echo $foo;
```

Output:

```
hello
good bye
```

Additional reading on it: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2015/new-in-php-7-null-coalesce-operator

Comment: Yeah, this is probably it but does this new operator no longer require `isset()`? Meaning, it will not return a warning if `$_GET['bar']` is not set?

Comment: According to this doc no notice will be thrown, `The coalesce, or ??, operator is added, which returns the result of its first operand if it exists and is not NULL, or else its second operand. This means the $_GET['mykey'] ?? "" is completely safe and will not raise an E_NOTICE.`. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary So no the `isset` is not needed. If you need this to work on older PHP deployments though it will not.

Comment: Thanks, for now, I figured a way to make it work < PHP7 `$foo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'bar) ?: 'hello';` although this looks "longhand"

Answer (score 0):

yes you would do it like this

```
$foo = isset($_GET['bar']) ? $_GET['bar'] : 'hello';
```

Comment: well yeah but that's not shorthand anymore

Comment: Yes it is that is how this conditional operator works. The if true value goes before the colon and the if false goes after it.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
$foo = isset($_GET['bar']) ? $_GET['bar'] : 'hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but is it something like:

```
$foo = isset($_GET['bar']) ? true : 'hello';
```

This will give you one(true) if that variable is set or just hello if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no (in PHP5 at least, see chris's answer for PHP7 only). For this reason I tend to use a helper function e.g.

```
function isset_or(&$variable, $default = NULL)
{
    return isset($variable) ? $variable : $default;
}
```

`$foo = isset_or($_GET['bar'], 'hello');`